# Neurosky Mindwave & Websockets

Tags: html, websocket

I'm currently trying to make a connection to the Neurosky Mindwave sensor using a websocket in HTML5. The Mindwave makes use of the Thinkgear Connector which I in turn use to connect to. I connect to the Thinkgear Connector using the default host address 127.0.0.1 with port 13854.

Basically all I do is this:

```
 var socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:13854');
```

If I run the script the Thinkgear Connector indicates there's a connection, except the .onopen event is never fired.  If I check the readyState I get a value of 0, indicating the connection has not yet been established. I think it's because in order to get one I have to send an authorization request first, which will be in the form of the appName & appKey, for example this:

```
{"appName":"Brainwave Test","appKey":"0139ccebc1902e0905b11bebc63c82eecada5784"}
```

The problem though is how to send an authorization request? Anyone have any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Hi. Did you ever figure this out? I'd like to try using WebSockets for the Mindwave too...

Comment: I think this guy ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cFROUiLrWr4 )  managed to make it work, but he hasn't shared any code.

Comment: Hey! Have you find out? I can use node.js module "node-neurosky" but that would require nodejs. I don't want to use nodejs. Can I still send these values{{appName, appKey}} for authorization ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not wedded to the idea of using the ThinkGear Connector driver, you can connect directly to the Bluetooth headset using the (Java) [mindwave-bluetooth](https://github.com/steveperkins/mindwave-bluetooth) library, register a listener for each event type, and push a WebSocket message out for each event. That's not quite what you're asking for, but it's an option in lieu of a full WebSocket-to-ThinkGear Connector solution.